# replace WITH clause with VIEW in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this.

```
with test1 as (      
select emp.empno, emp.deptno, emp.name, emp.hiredate, dept.deptname  
from emp, dept  
where   
 emp.deptno = dept.deptno  
 and emp.deptno = 72  
 and emp.salary > 5000  
)  
select inner1.*  
from (  
select 'abc' as title,   
1 emp_order,  
name, hiredate, deptname  
from test1  
UNION ALL  
select 'xyz' as title,   
2 emp_order,  
name, hiredate, deptname
from test1
) inner1
```

I am trying to remove the WITH clause completely and create a VIEW instead.The only problem I have is the dynamic value in the WITH clause.

I tried this:

```
CREATE VIEW testview as   
select emp.empno, emp.deptno, emp.name, emp.hiredate, dept.deptname  
from emp, dept  
where   
emp.deptno = dept.deptno   
and emp.deptno = 72   
and emp.salary > 5000
```

Updated query

```
select inner1.*   
   from (    
   select 'abc' as title,     
   1 emp_order,    
   name, hiredate, deptname     
   from testview    
   UNION ALL    
   select 'xyz' as title,     
   2 emp_order,   
   name, hiredate, deptname    
   from testview   
   ) inner1
```

In this case how can I pass bind values for salary and deptno cols in the view?

Comment: what dynamic value are you referring to, it is not creat what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then you want to use parameters in your view.

To do this you can use either of the below approaches:

a.) If your parameters are more or less static and not changing frequently you can use a  Table to store the value of this parameter. The values in this table can be updated by using a PL/SQL package or procedure. This table can then be refrenced in your view.

b.) If you require different parameter values for different sessions you can also Try using Application Context as given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_context.htm)

Hope it helps

Vishad

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove the common table expression in order to use this query in a view. If you remove the predicates and apply them to a query against the view they can pushed inside the CTE anyway.

e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW testview as   
select emp.empno, emp.deptno, emp.name, emp.hiredate, dept.deptname, emp.salary
from emp join dept ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno;

select inner1.*   
from (    
  select 'abc' as title,     
         1 emp_order,    
         name, hiredate, deptname     
  from testview
  where deptno = 72 and salary > 5000     
  UNION ALL    
  select 'xyz' as title,     
         2 emp_order,   
         name, hiredate, deptname    
  from testview   
  where deptno = 72 and salary > 5000     
) inner1
```

Comment: In your solution if the view's underlying tables are large and in case predicate pushing does not occur then won't the view's performance be poor?

Comment: That's two "ifs" in there, and failure to push the predicates is not at al likely. On the other hand if the CTE result set is large enough to be materialised then the subquery only gets executed once and performance is better than inline views that repeat the logic. CTE's have an upside as well -- if they didn't then they would not exist.